# Funcion str_pad ignora el relleno con múltiples espacios

Tags: php, mpdf

Estoy usando la siguiente instrucción

```
$relleno = str_repeat('*', 24); // Cambia 24 por la cantidad de asteriscos que desees

$importeConRelleno = str_pad($importe, strlen($importe) + strlen($relleno), '*', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Sin embargo, quiero que ese `'*'` se sustituya con un espacio en blanco `' '` pero al momento de hacerlo de esa manera, omite la instrucción y mi contenido pierde el llenado

```
Con asterisco
TEXTO**********100

Con espacio
TEXTO 100
```

Cuando mi resultado deseado es

```
Texto           100
```

Estoy usando una biblioteca llamada MPDF para imprimir el contenido, no se si esto afecte en algo. Agradecería mucho cualquier apoyo.

Comment: Posiblemente tu problema no sea de PHP, si no de HTML. Recuerda que HTML elimina automáticamente la repetición de espacios. En vez de espacios puedes usar [&nbsp;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity#reserved_characters) o bien, espacios normales dentro de la etiqueta [<pre></pre>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

Comment: Por fin di con la solucion 
Muchisimas gracias, si colocas la respuesta y no solo el comentario la marco como correcta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación de [MPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/), este genera pdf a partir de HTML. Entonces, es posible que tu problema no sea de PHP, si no de HTML.

HTML omite automáticamente la repetición de espacios, dejando solo 1 entre todos. La solución sería, en vez de espacios puedes usar `&nbsp;` o bien, usas espacios normales dentro de las [etiquetas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) `<pre></pre>`.